# HTML hyperlink wont open

Tags: html

I tried to open make the website to open "Kapital 2" but it doesnt work, it shows like a hyperlink but when i press on it doesnt happend anything. Any helpp?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hyperlinks</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>

        <a href="textauszeichnungen/3.html">Index 3</a>
        <a href id="Kapitel 2">Nach Kapitel 2</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: its not an page !! you have to define the page `href=""`

Comment: Sorry i made a mistake, its an folder . textauszeichnungen/3.html this is right but this not <a href id="Kapitel 2">Nach Kapitel 2</a>

Comment: may I Know Which Page you want to open on click on `Nach Kapitel` Link !!

Comment: <html>
 <head>
  <title>Hyperlinks</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
 </head>
 <body>
  2รถ
 
 </body>
</html>

This is second file, and when i press Kapital 2 i should see this symbole "2รถ" , but unfortunately doesnt work.

Comment: Name of your html page is mentioned in`href=" "` doubles Quotes

Comment: <html> <head> <title>Hyperlinks</title> <meta charset="UTF-8"> </head> <body> 2รถ </body> </html> This is second file, and when i press Kapital 2 i should see this symbole "2รถ" , but unfortunately doesnt work.

Comment: Dear i asking for page name ?

Comment: its code !! i am not asking for code !! i ask for name of page .. in which page this code is written !!

Comment: For Example : Like `3.html` is name of page in first hyperlink... like that what's the name of your second page  ?????

Comment: Do you have any social media, so i can send you photos , we dont have a page name , we have 3 files they're called 1.html,2.html,3.html .

Comment: mail me @ justplayyit69@superrito.com

Comment: This Code is Written In Which Page.. `<html> <head> <title>Hyperlinks</title> <meta charset="UTF-8"> </head> <body> 2รถ </body> </html>`

Comment: Its written in 2.html

Comment: and all 3 files are in same dir ??

Comment: Yes , actually 2 and 3.html are in 1 folder and the first one isnt.

Comment: okk fine !! Check My Updated Ans !! its Works For You !!

Comment: Tick as Right to accept my ans please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`2.html` Page Name Where You Want to Open an Page**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hyperlinks</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>

        <a href="textauszeichnungen/3.html">Index 3</a>
        <a href="textauszeichnungen/2.html" id="Kapitel 2">Nach Kapitel 2</a>
        <a href="1.html">Page 1</a>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: how do i do that ?

Comment: @MerisBihorac Check as a Right on Right side of my ANS !!